# What is this sharpened steel rod with rubber coating?

Tags: tools, fastener, nails

Got this at a yard sale in a bin with mostly random fasteners. Its about 3" long. It is very similar to a standard framing nail in diameter, if not slightly less. It has a tip like a nail but a dipped-looking rubberized coating.

Any ideas what this could be for? Someone suggested a small awl but given the very small size of the "grip" (if that's what it is) that seems unlikely.

I am in the USA.

[image]

Answer (score 38):

From the [Harbor Freight Hook Assortment](https://www.harborfreight.com/20-piece-storage-hook-set-67587.html) (item #67587), it's a straight line "hanging hook."

As noted in comments, it is a padded nail for hanging things. You hammer it in at an angle and then you can hang things on it. To avoid damaging the rubberized coating you gently walk the plastic off it, then drive it, then file down where you mushroomed it, then wet the plastic and slide it back on.

[image: storage hook assortment]

Answer (score 7):

It's a scriber used for marking wood, metal, etc. for cutting or drilling.

Answer (score 4):

Small pegs you can hammer into a board where you can hang things on, like a towel or your size 10 wrench

Answer (score -1):

Hardened point - then a tile cutter.

Comment: You mean like, to score it? Why such a miniscule handle? Or is it meant to be mounted in something?

Comment: @StayOnTarget bigger is not always better.

Comment: I can't argue with that in general. I guess this would be like holding a short pencil.

Answer (score -1):

That looks like a hand drill / hole maker. It is a type of awl (or, it could also be a bodkin for leatherworking or be a two-in-one as both) - thanks  @StayOnTarget

It is used to facilitate screwing in things with your hands. (hooks, curtain hangers, etc). These are fairly easy to screw in, but it can be a lot of work to get the screw to engage. Punch or twist a rough hole with the tool first and then engage the screw.